# ngModel not updated when ngOptions change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I prevent angular from updating the ngModel when the ngOptions array changes? Angular seems to set ngModel to null when the ngOptions array changed.

```
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = [];
    vm.selected = null;
    vm.getOptions = function(id) {
        $http.get().done(function(response) {
            vm.options = response.data;
        });
    };
}
```

say `vm.selected = "1";`

when `vm.getOptions` is called, the select options are being repopulated as expected, but angular seems to set `vm.selected` to null

How can I keep `vm.selected = "1"` after `vm.options` changes?

EDIT:

so I tried to set `vm.selected` after `vm.options` was set, however angular set `vm.selected` to null after my controller code runs.

so I tried to do:

```
$timeout(function(selected) {
   vm.selected = selected;
}, 0, true, vm.selected);
```

this successfully sets `vm.selected` to the previous value, however the view isn't updated.

EDIT:

the html is:

```
<select name="myOption" ng-model="vm.selected"
    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in vm.options track by option.id">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
```

here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YOE7UxWhEbCOuxFNA0zN?p=preview) to demonstrate. 1st, select an option, the click the update option button.

Comment: After your `vm.options` change, you need to specify `vm.selected` again

Comment: @Ronnie see my update

Comment: Show the HTML where you are using `ng-options`.

Comment: @Lex I added the html

Comment: I don't see `vm.getOptions` being referenced anywhere.

Comment: @bhantol I didn't include it above, but I have a $watch on another variable that I call vm.getOptions in

Comment: Can you create a plnkr ?

Comment: @bhantol I've added a plunkr

Comment: Best thing is to set model with 0th value of new options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.
>   [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)

You're using the id as value for ngModel. you cannot track `option.optionId` on this. You should use the option instance instead:

```
<select ng-model="vm.selected" 
        ng-options="option as option.optionTitle for option in vm.options track by option.optionId">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
</select>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selected = null;
  vm.options = [{optionId: 1, optionTitle: "one"}, {optionId: 2, optionTitle: "two"}];
  vm.updateOptions = function() {
    vm.options.push({optionId: 3, optionTitle: "three"});
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.selected" ng-options="option as option.optionTitle for option in vm.options track by option.optionId">
      <option value="">Select an option</option>
    </select>
    <hr/>
    vm.selected = {{ vm.selected }}
    <br>
    <button ng-click="vm.updateOptions()">Update Options</button>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: You're using a lower version of angular. This is not supported in versions > 1.4

Comment: @NikhileshShivarathri I updated to 1.5.7 and it works. This problem is documented on the ngOptions doc page. I don't know why you think that it's "not supported".

Comment: Sorry @hansmaad , i missed you're referencing the object 'option' to the model, yes it will work if you're referencing the object. But that would limit the developer to use the model as object. Please refer the link https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6379 this will explain you what i was talking about!

Comment: this was the issue. using the above ng-options will keep the selectedOption when options changes if the new options list contains the selectedOption, otherwise it sets selectedOption it to null

Answer (score 0):

Due to the numerous request for resetting the model on options change, Angular has made sure that the model value resets after the ng-options change for the versions > 1.4. However this will continue to work the same in the older versions of Angular.

[Click here for the reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6379)

In order to achieve the desired functionality, i would recommend you to use ng-repeat on options rather than ng-options on select.

```
<select ng-model="vm.selected">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in vm.options track by option.optionId" value="{{option.optionId}}">{{option.optionTitle}}</option>
</select>
```

look at this [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vGjsrxWAjFyYhzeWmHVK?p=preview)

hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of such situation I got burnt myself due to not treating the model as object of the option and resorting to property of the selected option

> How can I keep vm.selected = "1" after vm.options changes?

The `vm.selected` is a number not an object. It needs to be an object and must be the reference in the `options`

I made very small change to illustrate and get it to work.

First `vm.selected` treat it as object by following changes. Notice model is no longer optionId.

```
ng-options="option as option.optionTitle for option in vm.options track by option.optionId"
```

Second in the controller we are initializing the model as an object and a reference to the options.

```
vm.options = [{optionId: 1, optionTitle: "one"}, {optionId: 2, optionTitle: "two"}];
vm.selected = vm.options[1];
```

Also modified the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zzvcz4KcZlLjoe3IAGjY?p=preview) for other changes related to optionId keeping unique. However those changes don't contribute to the point in question.